# Splitting a column that contains Chinese Characters MySQL

Tags: mysql, substring, cjk

So I have a table that has a column 'full_name' and it stores chinese names in the format surname+given name.

What I want to do is split it into two columns: one for surname and one for given name. The surname is always one character and the given name is either one or two characters long. no spaces between. how can I split them?

When I tried to use:
`SELECT SUBSTRING(full_name, 0, 1) AS surname FROM citizens_CH`  it returned an empty column.. I read somewhere that Chinese characters in MySQL aren't actually of length one .. but no matter what I changed it didnt do anything.
Any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Please test this:

First create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE ChineseNames (FullName VARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO ChineseNames VALUES
('王沐宸'),
('李浩宇'),
('张沐辰'),
('刘茗泽'),
('杨奕辰'),
('黄宇泽'),
('赵浩然'),
('吴奕泽'),
('王沐');
```

Then Let's write the code:

```
SELECT FullName, LEFT(FullName,1) AS SurName,SUBSTRING(FullName,2,9999) AS GivenName
FROM ChineseNames;
```

Result It produces:

[image: GHJ]

Comment: To avoid this error:  `ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xE7\x8E\x8B\xE6\xB2\x90...' for column 'FullName'`, you should add `CHARSET=utf8mb4` at the end of your CREATE TABLE statement. (It might no be the default for everyone...)

Comment: thank you !! it works, didnt think about using left lol

Comment: @Luuk But it didnt give an error.. It just displayed an empty column..

Comment: Hello, Armonia. Nice to hear that your problem is solved. utf8mb4 is also the default charset for your system.